# Making a distance sensor for human interaction

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors, led, hardware

I want to make a sensor that senses a person between 1.5 m and 0.2 m, connected to an LED that is on 100% at 0.2 m and 1% at 1.5 m and gradually scales.

Is an ultrasonic sensor the best sensor to use here?

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE. You might find this helpful: [How to ask a good question for Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/how-to-ask-a-good-question-for-arduino-stack-exchange)

Comment: The 'best' sensor might be a $100K Computer vision system with 400 cameras.

Comment: are you talking about a swimmer underwater? ... you did not actually say anything about the usage of the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most arduino compatible ultrasonic sensors should work perfectly for your use case. You would just have to program the arduino then but I am going to assume that you know how to do that.

Here is a link to the one that I personally use: [https://www.amazon.com/HC-SR04-Ultrasonic-Distance-MEGA2560-ElecRight/dp/B01MA4O5G5/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1524520770&sr=8-3&keywords=ultrasonic+sensor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MA4O5G5)